# Cocos2d glDraw with smooth

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, drawing

I use `ccDrawSolidPoly` to draw something like this:

[image: Lines drawn by gl]

How can I add smooth to triangle edges?

Comment: Are you looking for anti-aliasing?

Comment: @dari, yes but I found only about sprite anti-aliasing